# Unable to find the powerplatform in Azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Unable to find the powerplatform in service connection in Azure devops
how to add the powerplatform connection in service connection in Azure devops

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the Power Platform  service connection, you need to install the Extension: [Power Platform Build Tools (2.0.5)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=microsoft-IsvExpTools.PowerPlatform-BuildTools) to your Organization.

Then you will get the Power Platform  service connection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are out of box (i.e from Microsoft) [Power platform Build Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tools)
you should be using this to perfrom your operations w.r.t power platform.

In addition connection with Power platform should happen [using ClientID and secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect#clientid-or-client-secret-based-authentication)

[For example look here to find out how to use connection srtring](https://dynamics-chronicles.com/article/azure-devops-dynamics-365-using-power-devops-tools)